# How to hide newly added comments after 24h?

Tags: comments

Hy

would like to know how can I hide newly added comments after 24h?
So in details what I would like to achieve is that when someone comment something his comment is visible 24h, after 24h that comment will be hidden.
But same person/or other persons can comment something new if they want, but that new comments will also be visible only for 24h...

So bassicaly comment area will always be available for new comments, but only new added comments will hide after 24h.
I'm using WpDiscuz plugin for commenting.

How can I do this?

WpDiscuz support told me that if I'm familiar with development, I can use the pre_get_comments hook and filter the comments.
Unfortunately I have no knowledge of PHP programming or any kind of custom coding.

tnx!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.